Integral convergence with floor function
I was given the following question :
prove $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \, dx$ converges.
Is it correct to show that if: $ \frac{\sin{x}}{x} - \frac{\sin{x}}{x - 1} \leq \frac{\sin{x}}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \leq \frac{\sin{x}}{x - 1} - \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ for all $x$ (since $x=1$ is problematic we can just apply that starting from $x=2$ and since it's finite it should be okay), then, since the function on the r.h.s and the function on the l.h.s are both converging and everything here is integrable. Hence, the middle function has to converge as well and from that we can conclude that our original function converges.
in the question itself, they gave a clue which is to try and show that $ \int_1^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin{x}}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right) \, dx$ is abs. convergent and from that I can conclude that the original function is also convergent, but I didn't manage to do so.
any help would be much appreciated!

Consider the expression
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|
$$
We can factor out $\sin(x)$ to rewrite this as:
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| = |\sin(x)| \left|\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{1}{x}\right|
$$
And we also have:
$$
\left|\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{1}{x}\right| = \frac{x - \lfloor x \rfloor}{x \lfloor x \rfloor} = \frac{\{x\}}{x \lfloor x \rfloor}
$$
Thus, the original expression becomes:
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| = |\sin(x)| \frac{\{x\}}{x \lfloor x \rfloor}
$$
We know that:
$$
\frac{1}{x \lfloor x \rfloor} = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2 + \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \{x\}} \leq \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2}
$$
This inequality holds because $\lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \{x\}$ is positive, so adding it to $\lfloor x \rfloor^2$ makes the denominator larger, thus making the fraction smaller.
Therefore, we can bound the original expression as:
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| \leq \frac{|\sin(x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2}
$$
Since $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$, it follows that:
$$
\frac{|\sin(x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2} \leq \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2}
$$
So we can conclude that:
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| \leq \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2}
$$
Now, define the function $f(x)$ as:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2}
$$
Given that the original expression is less than or equal to $f(x)$, we can use the Comparison Test to analyze the convergence of the integral
